# Java: Creating a GUI. Import or Extend JFrame?

Tags: java, inheritance, import, jframe, extend

I did a GUI by my own which extends a JFrame. And I saw a program code from advanced programmer who imports the JFrame. I might know the difference between import and extend. But what advantage is given by which sort of implementation?

Comment: In general you should NOT extend Jframe. Search the web for "composition vs inheritance" for discussions on this topic.

Comment: Who uses a JFrame as a member you mean. You always have to import JFrame no matter how you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

By "import" i presume you mean that your programmer friend's class **uses** a JFrame whereas your class **is** a JFrame.  I don't think extending a JFrame is "wrong", but my preferred approach is to create and configure a JFrame rather than extending it.  If there's really some protected method that you need access to then you might extend it but i'm sure that, in most cases, simply creating and configuring a standard JFrame is right - i have never found a need to extend it.

In other words, by inheriting JFrame with no real need to do that, you're just complicating your system.  This is a same argument you would have when choosing inheritance versus aggregation with any other class.  To find out what's right, you need to ask yourself if the class you're writing really **is** a JFrame which is a window widget.  I suspect that in most cases you are writing a Swing application which needs a JFrame but which isn't one itself - it's a Swing application with some other purpose.